# Lucene: How to search by specific term

Tags: java, search, indexing, lucene

I'm trying to do a Lucene search by a specific string term.
Eg: I had the tags 1-"Hello World", 2-"Hello, Steve", 3-"Helloween" and finally 4-"Hello" if I look for the last tag (hello), Lucene will bring all tags, because all of them had "hello" at some point. I need an operator or a logic that makes the search without "like".

There is a way to avoid this using the clause "must_not" (- operator) and the query will be:
`term:hello -term:world`. But this is not the case, cause I will need to find all other words that should not be in search.

```java
private <T> Query createQuery(final Class<T> clazz, String s, final String[] fields, final SearchFactory searchFactory, final Boolean allowLeadingWildcard) throws ParseException {
    final Analyzer analyzer = searchFactory.getAnalyzer(clazz);
    final QueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, fields, analyzer);
    Query query = null;
    try{
        query = parser.parse(s);
    } catch(...){...}
    return query;
```

My knowledge of Lucene is short, so I will place an SQL example to see if will be easier to understand

```
/*This is what Lucene is doing. It will bring "HELLO", "HELLO WORLD", "Hello, Steve"...*/
WHERE table.tag LIKE "%HELLO%" 
/*This is what I want. Match exactly the term "HELLO" and nothing more*/
WHERE table.tag = "HELLO"
```

I guess that this is the Analyzer used in the application:

```
public class AnalyserCustom extends Analyzer {

    @Override
    public TokenStream tokenStream(final String fieldName, final Reader reader) {
        final StandardTokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_36, reader);

        TokenStream stream = new StandardFilter(Version.LUCENE_36, tokenizer);
        stream = new LowerCaseFilter(Version.LUCENE_36, stream);
        return new ASCIIFoldingFilter(stream);
    }
}
```

And the attribute TAG is this:

```
...
@Field
private String tagname;
...
```

Any suggestions?
PS: I'm new to Lucene.

Comment: I missed the point of your final sentence "_I will need to find all other words that should not be in search._" Can you clarify what that means? You can [edit] the question - some more examples may help.

Comment: For example... if I had the tags 1-"Hello World", 2-"Hello, Steve", 3-"Helloween" and finally 4-"Hello" if I look for the last tag (hello), Lucene will bring all tags, because all of them had "hello" at some point. I need an operator or a logic that make the search without "like".

Comment: Can you edit your question and place this new example in there? Can you also show exactly what results you _want_ to get, as well as what you currently get? Sorry to push for this, but I don't understand what you mean by _an operator or a logic that make the search without "like"_ - and how that translates into what the end result should look like.

Comment: Also, what analyzer are you using, and what types of fields are created when you index the data? It's probably easiest to show the relevant code. All of these things can have a significant effect on how queries behave.

Comment: I've added some code. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I still don't know what type of analyzer(s) you are using, or what field type(s) were used when indexing. You still don't show examples of what results you _want_ vs. what results you currently get. The sample code raises more questions, without helping to answer any of the previous questions I had: Why are you using such an old version of Lucene? Why are you using a multi-field query parser?

Comment: My best guess: If you really want _exact_ matches for _entire_ field contents, then use [`StringField`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_9_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StringField.html) when you are indexing your data - do not use `TextField`. But if that is all you want Lucene to do then you may be better off not using Lucene at all, and using a relational database instead. Remember: Lucene's purpose is to rank documents according to relevance (as opposed to a binary hit/miss approach). Sorry I was not able to help more.

Comment: I appreciated your help and I apologize cause I starting to work with Lucene a few days ago and I'm a little lost... Version 3.6 it's because is a Legacy application. The tag attribute is using the @Field anotation. Using Luke I've discovered that the attribute is a String and not a Str.Field as u say. Sorry for the few pieces of information about the problem... as I say, I'm new to Lucene. Did you know whats the equivalent of StringField at version 3.6?

Comment: Regarding the `@Field` annotation: Are you actually using Hibernate Search? If so, you can add that tag to the question. I'm not at all familiar with Lucene 3.6, unfortunately, or with older versions of Hibernate Search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use to index the field, that will generate one specific token for the searched string, try with *KeywordAnalyzer*.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Using the annotation `@Analyzer(impl = KeywordAnalyzer.class)` worked correctly. But now I will have to reindex all data.